# How to create an MVC 5 app with login on a different domain (OWIN OAuth2)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin

I would like to create a Client application in MVC 5 with a log in page on a different domain.
What I want to achieve is a centralized authentication domain for all of my applications (MVC 5 web applications, Web Api's and Desktop applications as well).

I tried to use the example below:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

I can use the token to get resources from Web Api with both client type (website and desktop application), but I would like to use the claims and properties in the website as well and reach the web api with the token provided by the authorization server.

The only problem I have is that I can't set up and MVC 5 project to redirect to authorization server domain when the user is not authorized and after a successfully authorization redirect back to original domain and use the claims and properties which are encrypted into the token provided by the authorization server.

Can you provide me a sample or some articles with which I can start implementing the upper things by usin OWIN OAuth2? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a good palce to start http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Comment: @cecilphillip this is the link which I'm used, please read my question ;-)